# Setting gl_PointSize dynamically as shader attribute not working in WebGL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl, glsles

I'm trying to change `gl_PointSize` within my vertex-shader depending on an input. So, whenever I set ie. `gl_PointSize = 10.0` explicitly, everything is working out fine. After adding

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vColor;
attribute float vSize;

varying vec4 fColor;
void main()
{
    fColor = vColor;
    gl_PointSize = vSize;
    gl_Position = vPosition;
}
```

and calling

```
var size = new Float32Array([10.0]);
.
.
.
var sizeBufferId = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeBufferId);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, size, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var vSize = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vSize");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vSize, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vSize);
```

`vSize` is 2 after this so the buffer is created and bound correctly. WebGL Inspector also verified, that its content is 10.0.

Still, when calling my draw-code

```
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 2);
```

I only receive a blank canvas... Where am I wrong?

---

The rest of my code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
if (!gl) { alert("WebGL isn't available"); }

var colors = new Float32Array([ 1, 0, 0, 1,
                                0, 0, 1, 1]);

var vertices = new Float32Array([-0.5, 0,
                                  0.5, 0]);

var size = new Float32Array([10.0]);

// Configure viewport

gl.viewport(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
gl.clearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);

// Init shader program and bind it (invoked from another JS-file)

var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");

gl.useProgram(program);

// Load colors into the GPU and associate shader variables

var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colors, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);


// Load positions into the GPU and associate shader variables

var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);


// Load squares' size into the GPU and associate shader variables

var sizeBufferId = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeBufferId);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, size, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var vSize = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vSize");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vSize, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vSize);

alert("Color var: " + vColor + " | Pos var: " + vPosition + " | Size var: " + vSize);

gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I already figured it out myself. A silly and naive mistake, yet easy to overlook:

By calling `gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 2)` it is specified, that WebGL has to draw two independent points - each with its own coordinates, color AND PointSize.

So by altering `var size = new Float32Array([10.0, 10.0])` WebGL may now get two independent PointSize values out of `size`. Otherwise there would be some kind of NullPointerException within the WebGL state-machine.